# Noise power of attenuator-amplifier cascade

Tags: power, noise

Lets say we have matched circuit that consists of attenuator and amplifier in cascade and that this circuit is subjected to a noise from an outer source whose effective temperature is T. Find attenuation and noise factor of the attenuator.

We know that noise power is given as  Pn=kTB, where k=1.38*10^-23 J/K, T is a temperature and B is bandwidth of given circuit. Now, i found expression that says that noise power of attenuator is

P=kTB=kTBGa + kTaBGa, where Ga is gain of attenuator and Ta is temperature of attenuator, where first part on RHS is power due to noise from an outer source and second part on RHS is noise created inside of attenuator.

I have no clue how this can be true because, based on LHS we could conclude that all we need to determine noise power of attenuator is the temperature of outer noise and bandwidth of attenuator? Can anyone clarify this to me? Any help appreciated!

EDIT:

This is the block diagram i got along with this example:

[image]

Comment: Draw a diagram of the system

Comment: "I found expression..."  **Where**?  If it was on the internet, include a link.  If it was in a book, take a picture and paste it into your question with a reference.

Comment: @laptop2d I've added a block diagram of the system in my question.

Comment: @TimWescott I found it in hand-written paper professor gave me, so i dont know if this example can be found in some of workbooks, so i don't have any actual references to this.